# Clever way to manage browser history

Tags: javascript, ajax, browser-history

I'm trying to implement a decent navigation in a AJAX application. What I am doing right now is the following:

- Every time a user clicks an AJAX link, the corresponding call is performed and the hash is changed.
- Whenever a new page is loaded, I check whether the hash is present and make the corresponding AJAX call to update the page. This ensures that bookmarks will work as expected.
- Every 500ms I check if the hash is changed and perform the corresponding AJAX call. This takes care of users pressing the back/forward buttons, albeit with a sligth delay.

The third point is a bit annoying: I'd rather not have a timeout every 500ms just to check the hash, as most of the time it will stay the same.

> Is there a better way to manage this? I cannot think of any alternatives, but maybe I am missing something.

Please, do not point me towards ready-made solutions, unless you know they are based on a different mechanism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the "hashchange" event, which is to be implemented in HTML5. I'm not sure how good support is now... IE8 supports it, and I think Mozilla have their own implementation in a recent release. Other than that, there is nothing I'm afraid. Checking exery x ms is the way everyone does it.

Comment: IE8, Firefox 3.6, Chrome 4, and newer browsers support the hashchange event. Google's Closure Library (http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn-history/r8/trunk/closure/goog/docs/class_goog_History.html) and YUI 3 (http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/history/) will use this event if possible, otherwise falling back to polling schemes.

Answer (score 0):

maybe [this](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) is an interesting read, it is a ready made solution for the exact thing you are doing.
and no, until the hashchange is properly supported in every browser (read: ie), you will have to check manually

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin: http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/

The jQuery Address plugin provides powerful deep linking capabilities and allows the creation of unique virtual addresses that can point to a website section or an application state. It enables a number of important capabilities including:

- Bookmarking in a browser or social website
- Sending links via email or instant messenger
- Finding specific content using the major search engines
- Utilizing browser history and reload buttons

Comment: I has clearly stated "Please, do not point me towards ready-made solutions, unless you know they are based on a different mechanism."

Comment: I am sorry, Italian is my first language. For what I understand, it looks like you are looking for different mechanisms. I think it should be "Please, do not point me towards ready-made solutions, unless you know they are NOT based on a different mechanism". I actually think I overlook this sentence.